# Problema de herencia con clase Vector

Tags: java

estoy programando una clase Vectors que extiende la clase Vector de Java. Quiero implementar operaciones matemáticas elementales de los vectores en mi clase Vectors: suma, resta, producto escalar, etc. Al intentar implementar la operación suma de dos vectores me ha surgido el problema. He aquí el código:

```
package vectors.com;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Vectors extends Vector {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>(1);
    
    public Vectors(Vector<Double> v) { this.setV(v); }
    
    public Vector<Double> getV() { return v; }
    
    public void setV(Vector<Double> v) { this.v = v; }
    
    public Vectors opposite() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= this.size(); i++) this.set(i, -this.get(i));
        return this;
    }
    public Vectors sum(Vectors w) {
        Double f = 0.;
        for(int i = 0; i <= this.size(); i++) {
            f = this.get(i) + w.get(i);
            this.add(i, f);
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

El problema esta en la línea

```
f = this.get(i) + w.get(i);
```

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

***Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object Vectors.java***

Es decir; no puedo sumar dichos elementos, entiendo que por problemas de herencia y de ser de diferentes tipos.

Estoy utilizando java jdk 15.0.1.

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al ser Vector una clase genérica, como veo que usas todo Double, lo suyo sería heredar de Vector`<Double>` para que el compilador sepa qué tipo de valores va a tener Vectors

```
    public class Vectors extends Vector<Double>
```